# Send more than one entry in SOAP

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, nsurlconnection

I'm creating an app which communicates with a SOAP web service using XML. I need to send more than one entry at once. The SOAP page says I need to use a XML like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <InsertArrivaliOS xmlns="http://microsoft.com/webservices/">
      <GuestID>long</GuestID>
      <Key>string</Key>
      <NumberOfGuests>int</NumberOfGuests>
      <Table>string</Table>
      <Note>string</Note>
      <ArrivalDate>dateTime</ArrivalDate>
    </InsertArrivaliOS>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I'd like to send 2 InsertArrivaliOS nodes. Is it possible to do something like this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <InsertArrivaliOS xmlns="http://microsoft.com/webservices/">
      <GuestID>long</GuestID>
      <Key>string</Key>
      <NumberOfGuests>int</NumberOfGuests>
      <Table>string</Table>
      <Note>string</Note>
      <ArrivalDate>dateTime</ArrivalDate>
    </InsertArrivaliOS>
<InsertArrivaliOS xmlns="http://microsoft.com/webservices/">
      <GuestID>long</GuestID>
      <Key>string</Key>
      <NumberOfGuests>int</NumberOfGuests>
      <Table>string</Table>
      <Note>string</Note>
      <ArrivalDate>dateTime</ArrivalDate>
    </InsertArrivaliOS>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the InsertArrivaliOS in an other element with a list. When you define your schema, you can add another type with then as a sequence of unbounded InsertArrivaliOS elements.
so your xml code looks like that:

```
 <soap:Body>
   <listArrival xmlns="http://example.org">
    <InsertArrivaliOS xmlns="http://microsoft.com/webservices/">
      <GuestID>long</GuestID>
      <Key>string</Key>
      <NumberOfGuests>int</NumberOfGuests>
      <Table>string</Table>
      <Note>string</Note>
      <ArrivalDate>dateTime</ArrivalDate>
    </InsertArrivaliOS>
<InsertArrivaliOS xmlns="http://microsoft.com/webservices/">
      <GuestID>long</GuestID>
      <Key>string</Key>
      <NumberOfGuests>int</NumberOfGuests>
      <Table>string</Table>
      <Note>string</Note>
      <ArrivalDate>dateTime</ArrivalDate>
    </InsertArrivaliOS> 
   </listArrival>
  </soap:Body>
```

See the idea?
or is it not possible for you to modify the schema?

Comment: I understand that one SOAP message can call only one server function per request. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

If you can define server-side then what you can do, is to define method that accepts list of objects(set of arguments) instead of one. Like answer here.

If you cannot change service, then you can do wrapper that makes multiple calls for you.

Comment: agreed, this is valid only if you can change the WS itself.